# Calling your own Action method that returns IHttpActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

It seems maybe my question was unclear.  Here is what I am looking to do.

I am writing a web api that makes calls into another web api.  Inside of my API I would like to call to the UpdateAssignmentStatus method from the MarkAllTasksDone method.  I don't know what to do with the return type of IHttpActionResult, meaning how to process it.  How do I get the information that is being returned in the method.  In the UpdateAssignmentStatus method it returns a BadRequest with a message, a InternalServerError with a message, or an Ok with a message.  How do I get to that data?  Sorry, I should have provided that info before.

Just to add more here.  When I debug I can see that the actionResultUAS object is one of my return types that I stated in my UpdateAssignmentStatus method.  BadRequest returns System.Web.Http.Results.BadRequestErrorMessageResult, an Ok returns System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult, and InternalServerError returns System.Web.Http.Results.ExceptionResult.  I would assume that I will need to cast to each of these types.  Is there a good way to do that, maybe a generic way.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult MarkAllTasksDone(string projectID)
    {
        try
        {
            var assignments = GetAssignments("ASSGN/search?projectID=" + projectID + "&fields=taskID&fields=status" + "&apiKey=" + ApiKey);

            foreach (var assignment in assignments.Where(a => a.AssignmentStatus != "DN"))
            {
                var actionResultUAS = UpdateAssignmentStatus(assignment.AssignmentID, "DONE");
                //****how to get the ok or failure code and the returned data from the actionResultUAS object

                var responseMessageUT = UpdateTaskPercentComplete(assignment.TaskID, 100);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }

        return Ok();

    }


[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateAssignmentStatus(string assignmentID, string assignmentStatus)
{
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessage();
    try
    {
        var convertedStatus = ConvertAssignmentStatus(assignmentStatus);
        httpResponse = Put("ASSGN?ID=" + assignmentID + "&status=" + convertedStatus + "&apiKey=" + ApiKey);
    }
    catch (ApplicationException ae)
    {
        return BadRequest(ae.Message);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return InternalServerError(ex);
    }
    HttpResponseData httpResponseData = new HttpResponseData();
    httpResponseData.IsSuccessful = httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    httpResponseData.Content = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    httpResponseData.StatusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode.ToString();

    return Ok(httpResponseData);
}
```

Comment: Check my updated answer bellow. It will work exactly what you are looking for

Comment: @BasantaMatia That isn't what I am looking for.  I am trying to get the information out of actionResultUAS.  I'm aware of how to get the data from an HttpResponseMessage.  Sorry, if I am not understanding what you are trying to tell me.  Thanks

Comment: Please check the answer with content return this will work in your case

Comment: @SulayShah
If I change the UpdateAssignment method to return Content(code, data) the method is still returning an IHttpActionResult.  Which I don't know what  to do with it once it gets back to this object, actionResultUAS.  This is just an IHttpActionResult.  How do I get what I need from it?

Comment: @BrandonHunt please check the EDIT to your new request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
  return Content(httpResponse.StatusCode, httpResponse);
```

**EDIT** : as you requested the object from result, You can check the status code and read the response in object.

```
if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
 var result = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<'Your Model of assignment here'>();
}
```

This will return the model with the response.

Answer (score -1):

You need to return status code and info like this in your Api method,

```
return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, myData);
```

OR

```
return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, myData);
```

Then,

```
try
{
    var convertedStatus = ConvertAssignmentStatus(assignmentStatus);
    //httpResponse = Put("ASSGN?ID=" + assignmentID + "&status=" + //convertedStatus + "&apiKey=" + ApiKey);

    var http = new HttpClient { BaseAddress =  
                                new Uri("http://localhost:11111/") };
    //I'm passing the value as query string. See the bellow line
    string apiUrl = "api/ControllerName/ASSGN?ID=" + assignmentID + 
                    "&status=" + convertedStatus + "&apiKey=" + ApiKey";


    var _response = http.PutAsJsonAsync(http.BaseAddress + apiUrl, "").Result;

    var returnStatus = _response.StatusCode;
}
```

Comment: You are not getting question properly, @Brandon Hunt asked for how to use HttpResponseMessage result to IHttpActionResult output having actual status code returned from HttpResponseMessage.